# Create Azure service health alert in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

I just found out, if we create Azure service health alert with Terraform, with below code:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "servicehealth" {
  name                = "${var.client_initial}-MCS Maintain Service Health"
  description         = "${var.client_initial}-MCS Maintain Service Health Alerts"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  scopes              = [var.scopes]
  criteria {
    category = "ServiceHealth"
  }
  tags = var.tags
  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_group_id
  }
}
```

When I do `terraform apply`, it applies fine, but when I check on portal, no region is selected. You can't do the same via portal, if you do via portal, you have to select region or select all regions.

So if deploy via Terraform and no region is selected, does that mean it applies to all regions?

I see on GitHub, more granular control on this is still an open issue
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2996

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The region will be determined based on

```
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
```

where `resource_group_name` requires an instance of [azurerm_resource_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group):

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

and

> location - (Required) **The Azure Region** where the Resource Group should exist. Changing this forces a new Resource Group to be created.

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for the comments, so my resource_group_name is in australia_east. however, the service health region is not ticked for australia_east? nothing is ticked there

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar challenge when setting up Azure monitor Service Health Alert using Terraform.

**Here's how I did it:**

**Module Main File**

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "main" {
  name                = var.monitor_activity_log_alert
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  scopes              = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_scope
  description         = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_description
  enabled             = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_enabled

  criteria {
    category = var.criteria_category

    service_health {
      events    = var.service_health_events
      locations = var.service_health_locations
      services  = var.service_health_services
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_group_id
  }

  tags = {
    Environment  = var.tag_environment
    BillingGroup = var.tag_billing_group
  }
}
```

**Module Variable File**

```
variable "monitor_activity_log_alert" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the activity log alert"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the activity log alert instance."
}

variable "monitor_activity_log_alert_scope" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "The Scope at which the Activity Log should be applied, for example a the Resource ID of a Subscription or a Resource (such as a Storage Account)."
}

variable "monitor_activity_log_alert_description" {
  type        = string
  description = "The description of this activity log alert."
}

variable "monitor_activity_log_alert_enabled" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Should this Activity Log Alert be enabled? Defaults to true."
}

variable "criteria_category" {
  type        = string
  description = "The category of the operation. Possible values are Administrative, Autoscale, Policy, Recommendation, ResourceHealth, Security and ServiceHealth."
}

variable "service_health_events" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Events this alert will monitor Possible values are Incident, Maintenance, Informational, ActionRequired and Security. Defaults to all Events"
}

variable "service_health_locations" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Locations this alert will monitor. For example, West Europe. Defaults to Global."
}

variable "service_health_services" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Services this alert will monitor. For example, Activity Logs & Alerts, Action Groups. Defaults to all Services."
}

variable "action_group_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ID of the Action Group can be sourced from the azurerm_monitor_action_group resource"
}

variable "tag_environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "A mapping of tags which should be assigned to the resource."
}

variable "tag_billing_group" {
  type        = string
  description = "A mapping of tags which should be assigned to the resource."
}
```

**Module Main File for Creating Resource**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0.8"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.81.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "MyGlobalRG"
    storage_account_name = "myterraform"
    container_name       = "terraform-state-files"
    key                  = "azure-resources/global/monitor-activity-log-alert/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "main" {
  name                = var.monitor_action_group_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

module "monitor_activity_log_alert" {
  source = "../../../modules/azure/monitor-activity-log-alert"

  monitor_activity_log_alert             = var.monitor_activity_log_alert
  resource_group_name                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  monitor_activity_log_alert_scope       = ["/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}"]
  monitor_activity_log_alert_description = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_description
  monitor_activity_log_alert_enabled     = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_enabled
  criteria_category                      = var.criteria_category
  service_health_events                  = var.service_health_events
  service_health_locations               = var.service_health_locations
  service_health_services                = var.service_health_services
  action_group_id                        = data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
  tag_environment                        = var.tag_environment
  tag_billing_group                      = var.tag_billing_group
}
```

**Module Variable File for Creating Resource**

```
variable "monitor_activity_log_alert" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the activity log alert"
  default     = "my-service-health-alert-global"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the activity log alert instance."
  default     = "MyGlobalRG"
}

variable "monitor_action_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the Action Group can be sourced from the azurerm_monitor_action_group resource"
  default     = "my-global-mag"
}

variable "monitor_activity_log_alert_description" {
  type        = string
  description = "The description of this activity log alert."
  default     = "This activity log alert is to monitor the health of all services in the Global and US West 2 regions"
}

variable "monitor_activity_log_alert_enabled" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Should this Activity Log Alert be enabled? Defaults to true."
  default     = true
}

variable "criteria_category" {
  type        = string
  description = "The category of the operation. Possible values are Administrative, Autoscale, Policy, Recommendation, ResourceHealth, Security and ServiceHealth."
  default     = "ServiceHealth"
}

variable "service_health_events" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Events this alert will monitor Possible values are Incident, Maintenance, Informational, ActionRequired and Security. Defaults to all Events or Set to null to select all Events"
  default     = null
}

variable "service_health_locations" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Locations this alert will monitor. For example, West Europe. Defaults to Global."
  default     = ["global", "westus2"]
}

variable "service_health_services" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Services this alert will monitor. For example, Activity Logs & Alerts, Action Groups. Defaults to all Services or Set to null to select all Services."
  default     = null
}

variable "tag_environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "A mapping of tags which should be assigned to the resource."
  default     = "global"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, the location of the activity log alert is always `Global`. The activity log alert can be created at three levels: Resource level, Resource Group level, and Subscription level. Both resource group and subscription can contain multiple regions' resources. And you also cannot set the location when creating it. Not sure, but it seems the activity log alert does not have a special region except the `Global`.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for answering, but i dont think it’s what i was asking for. The scope is set to the entire subscription, what i was asking for is why terraform create service health alert without any regions selected? Does it mean all regions will be monitored?

Comment: @RogerChen Of course, yes. As I said, all the alerts have the same region `Global`, it means it.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your answers. Still have some questions. When you say activity log alerts only has global region, but in reality, when creating service health alert, it does have region filter to drill down specific regions. So does it mean it overwrites the global regions?

Comment: @RogerChen Yes, it means that overwrite the global regions. If not, it only can filter a single region, not multiple.